# WooCommerce - Do not authorize or capture on new order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, hook-woocommerce

Is there a way to set all new orders to "pending payment" (or some other status, maybe custom status?) without it auto changing to "on hold" or "processing"? What I'm wanting to do is basically have all new orders not only not capture CC payment (using Stripe), but also wanting it to not authorize. So, what I'm wanting to do is:

- Submitted
- "Pending Payment" (new order created, but not authorized or captured. Order status stay here until manual advance. I put in quotes because if this status HAS to be kept as-is with it auto connecting to the gateway, then maybe a custom status goes in between a submitted new order and Pending Payment...)
- Processing (authorize and capture payment)
- Completed

The whole reason for this is because my products are large and require us to box/weigh and manually get shipping prices (from various freight companies, etc). As it is now, new orders will auto authorize an amount and then put on hold. The problem is, we need to be able to manually go in and adjust shipping prices once we have a price and then add that to the order. There is no way to "re-authorize" for a higher amount (since we added shipping). So either we add a set flat rate amount per item for shipping (which would have to be more than the actual shipping rates could be) then come in and manually lower the shipping rate before capturing payment, OR we somehow don't let the new order to auto send to authorize.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: in this way i don't it's possible if you have online payment activated i believe you need to create some kind of offline payment gateway just like the bank gateway   to accept the orders and once they completed the checkout process tell your clients a link for online payment will be send to them once the total amount of order is calculated, but that need some kind of customisation and i recommend to hire a developer to do this logic for u

Comment: Ok. I'll look into this option. I'm a developer, so no need to hire. :)

Comment: cool good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to set the status of all upcoming new orders to 'Pending payment' regardless of any original status. Please note that the default order status is set by the payment method and you can't override it. The 'Pending payment' status will be set next to the default order status.

Add this to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'change_new_order_status', 10, 1 );
function change_new_order_status( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ) return;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'pending' ); //set status to Pending payment
}
```

There should be an option in Stripe payment method plugin to just authorize and not capture. You can enable that option but note that you cannot disable authorize.

Comment: I just tried this and this does me no good, as it changes the order status back to Pending Payment after the initial Payment Pending > On Hold, so it's still authorizing. I want to catch it before it ever talks to the payment gateway.

Comment: You can't prevent authorization in a payment method and you can only prevent charging. This function will set the order status back to 'Payment pending' and if you set the order status before payment, payment method will set it to its own default. You can try some offline payment methods if you don't even want to authorize the payment.